# Could we make quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, quarks

Given, that quarks are true "Atoms" (as the ancient greeks postulated) and tiny quantized energy amounts, are we capable right now of explaining how to transform energy directly into selected quarks, so that a device could make quarks and build the desired matter like LEGO?

Comment: I have to comment on the question. Quarks are not true atoms in the Greek sense, and the word "selected" quarks bothers me a lot. You _could_ build a collider which preferred certain resonances, but quantum mechanics would prohibit you from "selecting" which ones. Any detector setup would not have access to filter actual quarks since they are too short-lived and immediately freeze into particles. Can we make quarks ? yes. Can we select quarks ? no. Please help and re-phrase the question :-)

Comment: Thanks for your addendum. It helps. 
Reply to the last sentence: How? Wouldn't re-phrasing it lead to another answer? Now, that I know a bit more, of course I clearly recognize that this question is based on wrong assumptions. Perhaps I should entirely delete the question, but only because I know now better. I am unsure. Are there wrong questions, if there is not enough knowledge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question simply, the answer is "Yes" we can and do make quarks every day. Quarks are *not* true atoms in the ancient greek sense, they are, like all matter, physical manifestations of a field.

All that is needed to create quarks is a high-enough concentration of energy. This is available when particles collide and either annihilate (as in the case of particle-antiparticle collisions), or destroy the bonds between the nucleons as in the case of nucleus-nucleus or nucleon-nucleon collisions. At CERN's LHC for example, the collider regularly collides heavy nuclei consisting mostly of up,down and a tiny mixture of strange quarks, which results in a huge explosion of heavier quarks, all the way up to top quarks. These are "created" during the initial collision and "freeze" out of the quark-gluon plasma, then decay into lower-energy states, finally arriving back at the 1st-order matter we know in every day : protons, neutrons, photos, electrons, neutrinos and the odd muon.

Comment: I knew the LHC or DESY collide particles and quarks are released. But can humans create a specific mixture of quarks and "glue" them together, e.g. to create an electron?

Comment: Hi semo. That is best treated as a new quetion in my opinion

Comment: Since quarks cannot exist in isolation, but only in combinations with other quarks like in the proton, no, we cannot create individual quarks. And, electrons are not made up of quarks.

Comment: @Semo Quarks make up hadrons, but an electron is a lepton. Leptons are certainly not made of quarks, and to the best of current knowledge the two sectors (quarks and leptons) each represent a set of fundamental and indivisible particles. That is an electron is as basic as a quark, only because they don't participate in the strong interaction leptons are not confined and we can get at them much more easily that we can get at quarks.